# CKAN does not display maps

Tags: leaflet, ckan

I am working on a CKAN project and so far it is working well. However, even after installing `ckanext-mapviews` and `ckanext-geoview` and adding their respective plugin names to the CKAN config file, the maps seem to be taking forever to load. What could the problem be? Or what is the workaround for this? 
Thanks

PS: The types of files I'm trying to preview are `geojson`, `shapefiles` and `kml` files

Comment: Can you provide more information about the steps you take for  creating the maps, and the size of your files ? You can check example of maprs from geojson file on ckan demo : https://demo.ckan.org/dataset/educacionnn/resource/70f6109f-1f81-4cb7-bb46-49f67344d698

Comment: Hi Zoran, I followed the instruction on how to install the plugins from github then executed setup.py. Afterwards, I updated the config file with the respective plugin names. The files did not exceed 1MB because I just added for test purposes.

Comment: So, you are able to create map but it's not displayed ? Is there any errors in the console or on the server ?

Comment: Yes I was able to create the maps but the preview window has been loading forever. Let me share with you a resource to view

Comment: http://data.kayalab.org/dataset/test-dataset-with-multiple-resources

Comment: So there are errors in the console. What you have setup in your ini file as ckan.site_url ?

Comment: Hi Zoran, under my site.url, this is the link I put http://169.239.252.29

Comment: Ok, can you try with   http://data.kayalab.org, as your site url ?